# How to query the WordPress database to get posts of a certain custom post type, taxonomy and field?

Tags: database, query, wpdb, sql

I have a custom post type named `store` and I have a custom taxonomy `city`, I also have a meta box with a field that is stored with `update_post_meta( $post_id, 'store_postal_code', $postal_code );` it also has a post meta for `store_parking`.

How would I query the database in such a way it returns me rows in such a matter:

```
ID    post_title    store_postal_code    city         store_parking
1     Hilton        1234AB               Amsterdam    YES
2     Bijenkorf     1234AB               Rotterdam    NO
```

I tried this INCOMPLETE query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `post_type` = \'store\' AND `post_status` = \'publish\'';
foreach( $wpdb->get_results( $sql ) as $row => $post ) {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a custom query like this:

```
$amsterdamstore_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'store',    // This is your custom post type
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'city',    // This is your custom taxonomy
      'terms' => 'Amsterdam',    // The term you search for
      'field' => 'name',    // Check against the term's name (you might use 'slug', too)
    )
  ),
  'meta_query' => array(
      'relation' => 'AND',    // you could use OR, too - depending on what you want
      array(
          'key' => 'store_postal_code',    // Here goes your post_meta field's key
          'value' => '1234AB',    // Here goes your post_meta field's value
          'compare' => '=',
      ),
      array(
          'key' => 'store_parking',    // Here goes your post_meta field's key
          'value' => 'SOME_VALUE',    // Here goes your post_meta field's value
          'compare' => '=',
      ),
  )
);
```

These are the arguments you need for [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) or - if that is of more use to you - [get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). - Loop through the results, get_post_meta as you wold do normally and there you go.

BTW: You can combine the meta_query arrays to your liking: Add some, leave some, and you could even nest deeper and do something like AND ( A OR B ) ( C OR D )...

Comment: This helped me A LOT, THANKS! One question tho, I like to not only query but also receive the meta_value. Or is that something I must do separately when looping through the posts? with get_post_meta ?

Comment: Yes, you need to loop through the posts and use `get_post_meta`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a custom query and loop here, at least that's how I do it.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' =>'store',
  'taxonomy' => 'city',
  'term' => 'your list here'
  'posts_per_page' => 5
  );

$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if($loop->have_posts()):
  while($loop->have_posts()):
    do stuff here
  endwhile;
endif;
```

You will probably want to sort these so add the key/value pairs to your arguments for `order` and `orderby`.

The WP Codex is a fantastic reference for these types of questions.  The WP_Query class is your focus: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

And specifically the post type parameters: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: Re-reading your question, I see I ignored your post meta question.  It's all detailed on that Codex page though.  Let us know if you have any trouble getting the query built correctly.

Comment: This helped me A LOT, THANKS! One question tho, I like to not only query but also receive the meta_value. Or is that something I must do separately when looping through the posts? with get_post_meta ?